# How to add all third party jars(resolvable) in my OSGi bundle jar using 'bnd-maven-plugin'?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bnd, embedded-osgi

I am developing OSGi application using 'bnd-maven-plugin'
https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin

I have many third party jars in my project, referenced through maven.

When I create jar bundle using 'maven install', I will get it and when I deploy it on felix, it will not get resolved other dependent third party jars.

It is working with 'maven-bundle-plugin'
http://www.lucamasini.net/Home/osgi-with-felix/creating-osgi-bundles-of-your-maven-dependencies

POM file with '**bnd-maven-plugin**' given below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XYZ.Models</groupId>
    <artifactId>XYZ.Models</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>

                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below one is working POM for '**maven-bundle-plugin**'

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XYZ.Models</groupId>
    <artifactId>XYZ.Models</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>create-osgi-bundles-from-dependencies</id>
            <build>
                <directory>${basedir}/bundles</directory>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>wrap-my-dependency</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wrap</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <wrapImportPackage>;</wrapImportPackage>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: Hello @NeilBartlett Thank you. Where can I post query related to 'bnd-maven-plugin', I don't find much other than your nicely explained article for this plugin.

Comment: So why don't you just use *maven-bundle-plugin* if it works with that?

Comment: @UmeshRajani You can post questions here but I can't see an actual question above.

Comment: Hi Neil, Actually we have one project module which has 20-30 external jar dependency, when I just do 'maven install' I will get one myproject_osgi.jar and when I deploy on felix, it should resolve all the third party jar dependency, but it is not. So what is the way to do it? should I deploy all third party jar first on felix? (our higher tech team concluded to use 'bnd-maven-plugin' only)

Comment: I didn't understand this: "it should resolve all the third part jar dependency". Who is "it" here? Why would this happen? Have you provided all of the dependencies?

Comment: Hi Neil, I have given POM file with 'bnd-maven-plugin' above, when I do 'mvn install' I will get 'xyz.jar' and then I can install it on felix and if I start I will get the error like                                               "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle xyz [9]: Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.gson)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"

Answer (score 1):

The magic in `maven-bundle-plugin` is done by `<wrapImportPackage>;</wrapImportPackage>` which basically would add all your dependencies as resources in the generated jar file and configure the bundle classpath for you.

`bnd-maven-plugin` does not use instructions in the POM. You have to do that in `bnd` file. [This tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module) is specific for Liferay and Gradle, but it will show you an example of `-includeresource` instruction and how to set your bundle classpath.

Comment: The link is dead.... can you please elaborate directly in your answer?

Comment: @RalfUlrich I take it as a compliment that you believe I still remember the content of a post I was referring to back in 2016

Answer (score 0):

As above rightly mention about bnd-maven-plugin. you can also take a reference from [bndtools](https://bnd.bndtools.org/instructions/includeresource.html) and - [wcm.io](https://wcm-io.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WCMIO/pages/1267040260/How+to+switch+from+maven-bundle-plugin+to+bnd-maven-plugin)  already but just adding few line for example if it help.

```
 <configuration>
     <bnd><![CDATA[
         Include-Resource: <EXAMPLE-GROUP-ID>*.jar;<ANOTHER>.*;
     ]]></bnd>
</configuration>
```

you can use wildcard according to your requirement. i have just added example.